# How can I display the output for this?

Tags: java

I am using a file that has a first and last name and four sales numbers. I have an array created. I want to use all the people and sales figures to be displayed.
Here is the format of the file.

```
Willow Mary
154 189.5 95 76 63.51
```

Here's is what I was trying. It keeps going to my catch block.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment10 {
    public static final int NUM_SALESPEOPLE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SalesPerson[] list = new SalesPerson[NUM_SALESPEOPLE];

        try {
            int people = 0;
            Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("A10.txt"));

            while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
                String firstName = fileInput.nextLine();
                String lastName = fileInput.nextLine();
                double firstSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                double secondSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                double thirdSales = fileInput.nextDouble();
                double fourthSales = fileInput.nextDouble();

                SalesPerson person = new SalesPerson(firstName, lastName,
                        firstSales, secondSales, thirdSales, fourthSales);
                list[people] = person;
                people++;

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error opening file.");
        }
```

Comment: Add `ex.printStackTrace()` to the catch block so you can see what the exception is.

Comment: You should log the exception itself. Try `ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Please remove the `try-catch` block, let the `Exception` be thrown, then post the entire stack trace that appears in the console. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at Assignment10.main(Assignment10.java:24)

Comment: Line 24 is first sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is the format that you say, you are reading too many lines when you read each person. This code:

```
String firstName = fileInput.nextLine();
String lastName = fileInput.nextLine();
```

reads two lines from the file, yet the name appears on a single line. You are probably running out of lines when you get within three lines of the end of the file or else (more likely) trying to parse a line containing a name as if it were double values.

You also need to consume any trailing white space (including the newline) after reading the doubles. Try `fileInput.skip("\\w");`.

Instead, read the entire line of doubles as a single line and break it apart with code (e.g., using `split(" ")`) or by parsing in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
String firstName = fileInput.nextLine();
String lastName = fileInput.nextLine();
```

eats up 2 lines, so the following nextDouble() calls wont go where you want them to go.

Also

```
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file.");
    }
```

Is not always true, because you catch all `Exception`'s not only the ones that are file related.  At the very least also output the message your Exception is generating:

```
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + ex.getMessage() );
    }
```

Better still, catch all kinds of Exceptions generated in your program separately and provide a sensible error message, or recovery behavior per Exception type.